# VMWare Player 12

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player

may i know how do we export vmware file using vmware player 12. I have researched before and a lot of tutorial using vmware workstation rather than vmware player.Thanks for the help. im newbies in this vmware area

Comment: what host os is vmware installed on? what do you want to export it to exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VMware vCenter Converter](https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html) and export the virtual machine.

Follow these steps:

1. Install VMware vCenter Converter using standard settings at the virtual machine running in VMware Player 12.
2. Open VMware vCenter Converter and click `Convert machine`

[image: Convert Virtual machine]

3. Select `Powered-on machine` and `This local machine` options

[image: Use Powerd-on machine and This local machine]

4. Choose the format you want to export the virtual machine

[image: Choose format]

5. In options there is no need to change anything.
6. Export the virtual machine.